# creating a new string from a char array

Tags: java, string, char

I'm seeing some weird occurrence that if I don't use my original input string to be converted back into a string from a char array, the changes don't occur in the new string?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Type in String:");
  String theString = scan.nextLine();
  theString = theString.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
  char [] convert = theString.toCharArray();
  convert[0] = Character.toUpperCase(convert[0]);
  for(int i = 0; i < convert.length; i++){
       if(Character.isWhitespace(convert[i])){
            convert[i+1] = Character.toUpperCase(convert[i+1]);
      }
  }
  theString = String.valueOf(convert);
  System.out.println(theString);
```

If line theString on the 2nd the to last line was changed to lets say:

```
 String newString =  String.valueOf(convert);
```

or

```
 String newString = String(convert);
```

My output does not change the input! This program in summary capitalizes  the first character of every word in a string. Can someone explain why occurrence is happening?

Comment: Can you try explaining that again? I'm struggling to understand what you are expecting to happen and what is actually happening.

Comment: basically, input hello world => Hello World for output
However, if i change the name or variable of the char array to be converted into a string, it doesnt work

Comment: Well, if `newString` contains the converted string, but you print `theString`, obviously `theString` is printed. And `theString` is the initial, not converted String.

Comment: Your program works fine for me.  Are you sure you've pasted it in correctly?

Comment: Working fine.. voting to close. given test test as input and got Test Test.

Comment: i dont have a debugger, im using vim to code this. Note I'm just trying to understand why this is happening

Comment: You have a bug that you're unaware of.  If your input ends with a whitespace character, you get an Array Out Of Bounds when your conversion runs off the end of the string.

Comment: @ApprenticeProgrammer what is happening?

Comment: @ApprenticeProgrammer You can use jdb for debugging. It's shipped with your JDK.

Comment: Trying to write Java without a debugger is like trying to work as a builder, without having a hammer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its works. I tested it. I think you forget to change

```
System.out.println(theString);
```

to

```
System.out.println(newString);
```

Full code:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Type in String:");
      String theString = scan.nextLine();
      theString = theString.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
      char [] convert = theString.trim().toCharArray();
      convert[0] = Character.toUpperCase(convert[0]);
      for(int i = 0; i < convert.length; i++){
           if(Character.isWhitespace(convert[i])){
                convert[i+1] = Character.toUpperCase(convert[i+1]);
          }
      }
      String newString =  String.valueOf(convert);
      System.out.println(newString);    
}
```

input: hello world

output: Hello World

Thats what you expected :) And i fixed the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception when the String ends with a whitespace.

```
char [] convert = theString.trim().toCharArray();
```

Comment: you're right... stupid me... sorry!

Comment: then accept an answer to mark the question as answered :)

Answer (score 1):

It works fine, but what you want to consider is after scanning in the String to use

```
theString.trim();
```

This will remove whitspaces from the end, because right now if I enter "hello hello " (notice the space at the end) it will throw an OutOfBOundsException because of your `i+1` in the loop.

Or just check inside your loop if the index `i+1` exists.